# Insert Coin, Feed Beast: mine.stackgaming.com

Tags: discussion, community, minecraft

This is a formal notification of our commmunity [FTB](http://feed-the-beast.com/) ([Ultimate](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Ultimate_Mod_Pack)) Minecraft server. It is a whitelisted server, so if you want access ping @fredley or @RonanForman in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk). If you can't for [some reason](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4fd41e751c30c98cadb60188111490a0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG), leave a comment here instead.

[image]

The server is at `mine.stackgaming.com`, and all you need to play is the [FTB client](http://feed-the-beast.com/#download_wrapper). The installation of FTB-modded Minecraft will not interfere with your vanilla game at all (as long as you don't load it into the same folder, which it doesn't by default).

### House Rules

- Griefing is prohibited, griefers will be blacklisted from this and all future Arqade Minecraft servers.
- Please keep your quarrying, or any seriously destructive landscaping to the Mining World. There are portals to there from NightGo Industries. You can create your own [linking books](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Linking_Book) to set up your own portals. Unfortunately, there is no way to return to the overworld as of now. Please create a following linking book for your own safety.
- Ops are @fredley, @RonanForman and @ThomasMcDonald, ask us if you have any queries, or if you have any problems.
- This is a community server. Play nice, respect others, don't do anything stupid.

**[Visit the online map!](http://mine.stackgaming.com)**

Comment: This post is primarily an endpoint for our [community ad](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6844/3610).

Comment: Sounds like fun! Especially with the Direwolf20 pack, and not the Mindcrack Gregtech-hardmode pack...

Comment: Gah, I should get on this...but I'm running my OWN DW20 server these days so... yeah >.<

Comment: Wait, server reset?  Does that mean my seaside log cabin is gone?

Comment: @fredley how do we become white listed?

Comment: @Scootaloo `if you want access ping @fredley or @RonanForman in chat.`

Comment: I have the urge to flag this as NARQ.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ This is meta, the rules are different.

Comment: Should this post be updated to say that the server is gone, or will it be coming back in another form?