# What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, obsolete-questions

Minecraft's new (as of 1.5) water physics mean that [this question no longer makes sense as a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10318/how-can-i-level-water) - the situation can no longer arise.

Should this question be closed/deleted?

Comment: A similar example is my openfeint question (which I deleted, but 10kers can probably still see).  I'd link it, but I can't see it either.

Comment: Related: [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797)

Comment: Related: [What do we do with questions about games that can no longer be played?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5565/181240)

Answer (score 9):

## No

This particular question *is* still valid for people who aren't playing Minecraft 1.5 for whatever reason (e.g., they're playing [FTB](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6846/3610)). I believe an answer should be added explaining the current situation, but that the question be left as it is.

Comment: I agree that if the question is still valid to a particular subset of people playing, that there needs to be a method of distinguishing that this question is only relevant to that subset of people playing to avoid confusion

Comment: Editing a quote box into the top of the question is not hard, and would be appropriate.

Comment: @fredley Okay, but what do we do once FTB syncs with the current release? And for right now, wouldn't it actually be more appropriate to tag this question with the FTB tag as a result?

Comment: @badp No! FTB is one example where people are playing on an older version of Minecraft, but it is by no means the only one. There are other mods and modpacks, and plenty of other reasons. Because of this it's impossible to tell when a question becomes 'useless' *unless* you start monitoring how many hits it's getting, but at the point at which it's getting no hits does it even matter any more?

Comment: @fredley I'm only considering FTB as a possible exception to the more general rule because it's the mod du jour around here.

Comment: @badp I'd consider Minecraft to be an exception in general - older versions are still played for various reasons. We already make an exception for *future* version questions after all!

Comment: I gulp as I say this, but could we invent a tag for this?  Like [tag:obsolete] or something like that?  I'm not seeing the pitfalls other than maintenance, which seems necessary in any scenario.

Comment: A tag would be great for those of us who know to check them, but some people don't, such as those arriving from Google. I have had to audit websites for user-friendliness before, and you have to go into it assuming the standard user will not read most of the important information on the screen unless it is painfully obvious.

Comment: @EBongo I'm afraid that, while potentially useful, such a tag wouldn't survive community scrutiny for long. See also what happened to [our spoiler tag.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/spoiler-alert-spoiler-dies)

Comment: [obsolete] would be a meta tag. Don't do meta tags.

As has been said: There's various reasons to run an older version of minecraft (heck, the client version has to be in sync with whatever server one connects, even). Add in a quote box with bold text, or a headline that says "For versions X", and supply further answers for other versions that act differently

Comment: @badp You're right, but that also gives me another idea.  For spoilers we have spoiler markdown.  Could we add obsolete markdown?  Something visually obvious like what AliceRees points out?  Maybe making the question look more like closed questions, without it really being closed.

Comment: @EBongo I don't honestly think balpha wants to add any more complexity into Markdown; if you think this is a good idea I encourage you ask about it on Meta.